# How to implement atomic getOrDefaultWithPut() based on getOrDefault() in ConcurrentHashMap?

Tags: java, collections, synchronized, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap

[ConcurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) supports atomic [`getOrDefault(Object key, V defaultValue)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-), which

> Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or the given default value if this map contains no mapping for the key.

My problem is:

> How can I enhance `ConcurrentHashMap` by providing an atomic operation, say `getOrDefaultWithPut(Object key, V defaultValue)`, which
>
> "Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or first ***put*** the the given default value into the map and then return the default value if this map contains no mapping for the key.`"

---

***My solution:***

Currently I have a `Wrapper` class of

```
 private ConcurrentMap<K, V> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

The method is:

```
public synchronized K getOrDefaultWithPut(K key, V defaultValue)
{
    map.putIfAbsent(key, defaultValue);
    return map.get(key);
}
```

> 1. Is this implementation thread-safe?
> 2. Is `synchronized` necessary? What bad would happen if it is removed?
> 3. If `getOrDefaultWithPut(K key, V defaultValue)` is the only public method of `Wrapper`, is this implementation thread-safe and is `synchronized` necessary?

Comment: By using synchronized, you seem to have lost all parallelism that concurrent hash map internally provide.  Also, you should use getOrDefault in your method.  Only case in which your code won't work is if someone removed the key in between the statements map.putIfAbsent and map.getOrDefault, in which case you would get a default value but key won't be present in map (which can be ideally correct too depending on your use case)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use [`computeIfAbsent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-)

> If the specified key is not already associated with a value, attempts
>   to compute its value using the given mapping function and enters it
>   into this map unless `null`. The entire method invocation is performed
>   atomically [...]
>
> **Returns**
>
> the current (existing or computed) value associated with the specified key, or `null` if the computed value is `null`

Provide a `mappingFunction` which generates your default value and this will satisfy your requirement.

> Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped

That's the existing value.

> or first put the the given default value into the map and then return the default value if this map contains no mapping for the key

The method will insert the computed value (the default), if not `null`, and return that computed value.

---

You won't need `synchronized` with this solution. The method invocation is atomic and it's therefore thread safe.

Answer (score 4):

Almost. You should use the value, returned by `putIfAbsent` instead of doing another `.get`, and you don't need it `synchronized` (it's fairly useless in this case anyway, unless all other callers know to synchronize as well, which defeats the purpose of it being `ConcurrentHashMap`:

```
public V getOrDefaultWithPut(K key, V defaultValue) 
{
  V val = map.putIfAbsent(key, defaultValue);
  return val == null ? defaultValue : val;
}
```

*Edit*: `computeIfAbsent` works too, this is just a little bit simpler, since you don't need to define a function in this case, and is also, I think, more informative as an answer, as it actually fixes the problem with your original approach, rather than replacing it with a different one.